# How can I ensure that non-clients have no client management?

Tags: formula, picklist, record-type

My formula so far:

```
AND(
OR(
ISPICKVAL( Type, "Prospect"),
ISPICKVAL( Type, "Is this a Prospect or User?"),
)
,
ISPICKVAL( Client_Management__c,"")
)
```

The other Types of accounts are either clients or ex-clients.

But for the Types specified, I'd like for the Client Management field to be required to be blank (it is a picklist field by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule has to evaluate to TRUE in order to cause a validation error, so you are probably looking for:

```
AND( 1 = CASE(Type, "Prospect", 1, "Is this a Prospect or User?", 1, 0),
     NOT(ISPICKVAL(Client_Management__c, "")))
```

CASE is simply used to reduce the impact of the compiled function size, although I do find that this form is a bit easier to read.

Comment: Much more readable with the leading `1 = CASE(...)`. I think the other way around tripped some people up.